# read_proc_t and file_operations in procfs

Tags: linux-kernel, procfs

I'm now studying proc file system. I now know that read_proc_t function is called when the proofs file is read, and so for write_proc_t function when the proofs file is written to. But I also find the file_operaitons* field in the definition of proc_dir_entry, and this example code (http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x810.html).

So I'm confused that what would happen if I provide both implementations of read_proc_t function and the read function in file_operations structure? Which has the precedence over the other? Could one be overwritten by the other? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you register proc-entry, `proc_register()` checks if you specify `proc_fops`. If you don't, it will set default file operations for procfs. Default operations calls your `proc_read` and `proc_write`. So, if you specify `proc_fops` by yourself, `proc_read` and `proc_write` members will not be called.

In linux-3.10 there aren't such things as `write_proc_t` and `read_proc_t`. `proc_dir_entry` has no members `read_proc` and `write_proc`. Instead, only `proc_fops` is used.

Comment: Thanks very much rasen! Could you please tell where to get such information, like from the source code, the man page, other documentations, etc. Because I've searched the web, but it seems little useful information I could get. Thanks again!